# Location of code so that 'SharedPreferences' works with 'onOptionsItemSelected'

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, anko

I've been trying to get these two to work but no matter how I rearrange the code, there is always something complaining: either a var that has not been initialized or a fun.

This are the offending snippet:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    var sp : SharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("com.example.downloadtest",0 )

    fun storeUnits(unit:String){
        sp.edit().putString("units", unit).apply()
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        if (item.itemId == R.id.settings){
            //toast("Settings clicked")
            alert("Choose Units") {
                title = "Units"
                positiveButton("Imperial") {
                    toast("Imperial Measurements Chosen")
                    storeUnits("imperial")
                    
                }
                negativeButton("Metric") {
                    toast("Metric Measurements Chosen")
                    storeUnits("metric")
                    
                }
```

The var **'sp'** needs to be where it's at (right?). The fun **'store units'** is also placed ok. However, I cannot place the **'override fun onOptionsItemSelected'** inside another **override** function; but if I place it outside it doesn't work with the other two.
Please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both onOptionsItemSelected method and your storeUnits method should be **outside** of the onCreate method. You can instead make **sp** a global variable:

Declared this as a global variable before your onCreate method(inside the activity class but outside onCreate):

```
lateinit var sp : SharedPreferences
```

Then initialize it inside onCreate method:

```
sp = this.getSharedPreferences("com.example.downloadtest",0 )
```

Comment: That did it. Oya, I appreciate your help on this.I will have to read up on lateint.

Comment: lateinit is optional. It is for not declaring sp as nullable. You can simply declare it as var, but then you need to initialize it as null and use a nullable type. The essential point is to make the scope of the field the whole class so that you can access it from other methods as well.

Comment: And that is what I was desperately looking to do, but was not aware that I could use the lateinit; and that is why I cried for help..... and it won't be the last...